# Limit access to local IPs only on Jboss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Jboss 7.0 is (by default) configured to limit the access to the local ip by defining this in `standalone.xml`:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces
```

I know I can change that to make it publicly available to all ips by putting this:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces
```

But how can I limit this to local IPs only, e.g. all IP addresses that start with `10.x.x.x`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this could help: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Interfaces+and+ports

```
<interface name="default">
   <!-- Match any interface/address on the right subnet -->
   <subnet-match value="192.168.0.0/16"/>
</interface>
```

In this way you can match all addresses in the given subnet.

Comment: Is there a way to configure more than one subnet-match?

Comment: I still can't get this to work. Unfortunately I have to access the Jboss server from a different subnet. The JBoss Server itself has a c-class IP: `192.169.200.17` and lives in an extra zone. I need to access it from another network with a a-class ip of `10.x.y.z`. Can I add a subnet that is different from the servers IP? (Maybe a dumb question - I am not really a network guy.)

Comment: Try to add several interfaces, as in linked doc. I am also not a network guy, so just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Additional (to the doc in the link) I found all kinds of examples by searching through gibhub. There were a few test classes using a `standalone.xml` which showed different configurations. Unfortunately without luck. But I guess our network setup is very special.

Comment: This option is not working, Do we have any RHEL document for this ?